# Kohana и css

Tags: css, kohana

Как решить проблему того, что css файл в главном шаблоне подключается только при вызове индексных методов? При вызове остальных, страницы отображается без css.

Comment: Написать шаблон так, чтобы подключался всегда, разве не очевидно?:)

Comment: Нууу)) у меня он прикреплен в начале...или както можно еще подругому прикрепить?

Comment: <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Он в одном случае, когда дефаултный индекс срабатывает - показывает, а когда не дефаултный - не отображает css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте путь абсолютным, не `css/style.css`, а `/css/style.css`.

Comment: С абсолютным он вообще не отражает.

Comment: т.е. изменяется вид, но какие-то методы вообще не знакомые применяются к дивам и т.д.

Comment: ну пропишите полностью путь к css, как там у вас, чтото типа:<br>
/view/css/style.css или чтото в  этом духе, я кохану уже не юзал с год, просто сделайте так чтобы путь к css не зависел от текущего url адреса текущей страницы...

Comment: частично понял...я засунул в html картинку лежащую в одной папке с Css, и путь тоже прописал css/logo.jpg и она тоже не отобразилась, а url показывает, как:
http://localhost/kohana/article/id/css/logo.jpg

Comment: Ну т.е. постройте все пути так чтобы они начинались с `/` и вы навсегда забудете о такого рода проблемах, гарантирую :)

Comment: а ещё лучше брать кохановские хелперы и юзать HTML::style(''); в таких случаях. Тогда точно забудете о подобных проблемах